# Why was Maggie Naird put in jail?

Tags: plot-explanation, space-force

I'm talking about the Netflix web-series [*Space Force*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9612516/).

In S01E01, we get to see that General Mark R. Naird got his promotion as 4-star general and was appointed as head of space force. So, he has to shift in a remote location, which is used as the head-base of space force.

[image: Maggie Naird]

Suddenly, we are taken to another scene where the general visits a jail to meet with his wife Maggie Naird (Lisa Kudrow). Did I miss anything? When was she put in jail and for what reason?

Comment: I think it’s part of the humor that we don’t know.

Comment: Revealed in future, probably?